# Saving a large-size picture in a small-size window

Tags: c++, mfc

I am new to MFC. Now I have the following question:
I have a large-size picture (e.g. size of 2000*2000) display in a small-size window (e.g. size of 640*480). No wonder that the picture cannot show itself fully without zooming out. I know I can save the original picture without losing any pixel if the picture can fit into the window, however, I cannot do this at this time:

```
CClientDC SHDC(this); //"this" is a CMDIChildWnd derived class
CDC memDC;
CRect rect;

GetClientRect(&rect);
memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&SHDC);
CBitmap bm;
int uWidth = rect.Width();
int uHeight = rect.Height();
bm.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&SHDC, uWidth, uHeight);
CBitmap *pOld = memDC.SelectObject(&bm);
memDC.BitBlt(0, 0, uWidth, uHeight, &SHDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
......
```

The saved picture only show the client area, but I would like to get all of the picture saved.
Anyone who can help me? Thanks in advance.

Xi

Comment: Are you asking how to implement scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `BitBlt` try `StretchBlt`. It'll handle the shrinking for you.

> The StretchBlt function copies a bitmap from a source rectangle into a
>   destination rectangle, stretching or compressing the bitmap to fit the
>   dimensions of the destination rectangle, if necessary. The system
>   stretches or compresses the bitmap according to the stretching mode
>   currently set in the destination device context.

If you want higher quality stretching/shrinking look at GDI+. There's a variety of interpolation modes you can use. More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0fsyd4e.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt work for me. I just want the original pict (in the example, the 2000*2000 pixel picture). Someone just told me there is no way to achieve this on earth, is it?

Comment: Are you trying to shrink the picture to fit a smaller window or something different?

Comment: I tried this method, it actually returns a original size picture. But it causes lower quality - the picture becomes blur. This could be a option for me. But is there any other better solution?

Comment: @XiDuan, if you use GDI+ you should specify `HighQualityBicubic` for the resizing mode.